# Django not sending debug errors in production

Tags: python, django

I have a django app running on production but server errors are not sent to the established e-mail.
This is my settings.py:

```
ADMINS = [('Foo the man', "******@gmail.com")]
SERVER_EMAIL = os.getenv('SERVER_EMAIL')
EMAIL_HOST = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST')
EMAIL_HOST_IMAP = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_IMAP')
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
```

Regular e-mails from within the app are being sent correctly, but debug errors are not sent and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

You can check followings:

- `DEBUG` is set to `False`

  Error emails will not be sent if the `DEBUG` setting is set to `True`
- Review the `LOGGING` configuration

  ```
  LOGGING = {
      'version': 1,
      'disable_existing_loggers': False,
      'handlers': {
          'mail_admins': {
              'level': 'ERROR',
              'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
          },
      },
      'loggers': {
          'django': {
              'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
              'level': 'ERROR',
              'propagate': True,
          },
      },
  }
  ```
- Check your spam/junk folder. Sometimes these error emails are classified as spam
- Error type
  Django only sends error emails for unhandled exceptions. If you're catching all exceptions in your views or middleware, then Django won't send an email

Comment: Hi! Debug is set to FALSE, spam/junk folder as well as sent folder on the host email don't show any messages, and the error I'm getting is unhandled, so the only thing missing is the logging settings which I haven't declared explicitly, but as far as I know what you wrote is exactly what is loaded as default when you don't declare something different in django...so at this point I'm quite lost. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I'm checking and the only thing that changes from the default logging config is the level in django loggers which by default is 'INFO' but it shouldn't make a difference since my error is internal server 500 and is handlede as error level.